# OrientDB - Trouble storing data from a java application

Tags: database, nosql, orientdb

I am trying to store triplets inside of OrientDB as Vertex-Edge-Vertex relationships inside of a Java application that I am working on. My understanding of using OrientDB is that I can use the Tinkerpop API and instantiate a graph like this:

```
OrientGraph graph = new OrientGraph("local:/tmp/orient/test_db");
```

That is really all I do to instantiate the graph, then I try to connect vertices with edges in a loop like this: (Note that a `Statement` is a triplet consisting of subject-relationship-object.)

```
for (Statement s : statements) {

     Vertex a = graph.addVertex(null);
     Vertex b = graph.addVertex(null);
     a.setProperty("Subject", s.getSubject().toBELShortForm());
     RelationshipType r = s.getRelationshipType();
     if (s.getObject() != null) {
         b.setProperty("Object", s.getObject().toBELShortForm());
         Edge e = graph.addEdge(null, a, b, r.toString());
     }
     else {
         b.setProperty("Object", "null");
         Edge e = graph.addEdge(null, a, b, "no-relationship");
     }

}
```

I then loop through the vertices of the graph and print them out like this:

```
for (Vertex v : graph.getVertices()) {
     out.println("Vertex: " +v.toString());
}
```

It does print a lot of vertices, but when I log into the server via the command line, using `server.sh`, all I see are the 3 records for `ORole` and 4 records for `OUser`. What am I missing here? Because it seems like although my java program runs and completes, the data is not being put into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, at least for now, seems to be not to use the Tinkerpop API but rather the Orient API directly. This is the same thing I was doing with Tinkerpop, but using the OrientDB API. This actually does store my data into the database:

```
for (Statement s : statements) {
            ODocument sNode = db.createVertex();
            sNode.field("Subject", s.getSubject().toBELShortForm());
            sNode.save();

            ODocument oNode = db.createVertex();
            if (s.getObject() != null) {
                oNode.field("Object", s.getObject().toBELShortForm());
                oNode.save();
            }
            else {
                oNode.field("Object", "null");
                oNode.save();
            }

            RelationshipType r = s.getRelationshipType();
            ODocument edge = db.createEdge(sNode, oNode);
            if (r != null) {
                edge.field(r.toString());
                edge.save();
            }
            else {
                edge.field("no relationship");
                edge.save();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create the Graph under the Server's databases directory. Below an example assuming OrientDB has been installed under "/usr/local/orient":

```
OrientGraph graph = new OrientGraph("local:/usr/local/orient/databases/test_db");
```

When you start the server.sh you should find this database correctly populated.

Lvc@